# App studio connection issue with SS 5.10.4

Tags: servicestack

I Am trying to add a running project to app studio but I get error that I need at least SS v 5.8.1

[image]

I am using version 5.10.4 from myget.  I have updated `app` to latest version 5.1.13.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Can you first verify that your `/metadata/app.json` is returning a valid JSON response, if it is try launching studio with `app://studio?debug` to see if the detailed logging contains any more info about the error.

Comment: Thanks the debug showed issue, port 5002 was being used by another process